# MIT OpenCourseware Linear Algebra Exam Solution Error

Tags: linear-algebra

I just worked through an MIT exam and there seems to be some errors in the exam solutions: http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring15/Exam1_s15_sol.pdf

So sanity check:
Q1b. The nullspace vector should be (1,1,0,0), not (1,-1,0,0)
Q1c. The answer provided ignores the transpose operation. The answer should be the same as Q1a.
Q1d. Uses the wrong answer from Q1b.

Comment: Errors in the "answers at the back of the book"? That ain't news.

Comment: Yep, that's a mistake in Q1(b)